# print one part of an array

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array populated as shown:

```
guess.append( ( v.relation(y[0],buildvector(im3)),x) )
```

The variables populating the array are part of a loop and defined earlier in the code. This array then gets sorted and is printed using:`print (guess[0])`

This returns: `(1.0, '2')`
The numbers for which vary based on input.

I am trying to print the "2" portion of the array now. I have tried using an improvised "mid" function but did not have much success and am guessing there is a much simpler solution to this.

Comment: what you mean by *"2" portion of the array* ? can you show us the code that you had so far? or show an sample input and expected output!

Comment: Maybe you want to do `print(guess[0][1])`?

Comment: Thank you rutsky, I have been messing around with this so much modifying the rest of the code to split the array differently but such a simple solution!! Could you please post it as an answer so I can select it?